# 441 days in beta. Will Movies.SE make it?

Tags: support, discussion, recent-activity

It's been more than a year since Movies.SE started public beta, and more than two years since proposed. The following statistics show the current progress of the site:

[image: screeny]

Is our site going to complete the beta period (which has taken a long time, IMO) and become a full member of the SE network? What is it that prevents the site from being promoted as a full member? The stats seem satisfactory to me.

Comment: Hi Mehper.  I almost left this one open, as its been 2 months since this (duplicate) was asked.  I think this question is fine once in a while, but I think the answers from December still stand.  Please do continue to ask though, as I am as keen as anyone to make it out of Beta.

Comment: You could always ask Robert via a comment on his answer whether anything has changed, or whether he has news.

Comment: Hi @iandotkelly, thanks for pointing it out, I wasn't aware of the duplicate.